# jupyter notebook kernel dies when loading mat files using scipy

Tags: scipy, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook for my python work. I have a large dataset .mat file which I am trying to load using scipy package using loadMat function. When I am trying to load my data file, my jupyter kernel dies and restart without any error in the console. 
python console works fine and it loads data properly.

I am using ubuntu machine.
Can someone please let me know what is the issue with the jupyter notebook

Comment: Does the jupyter loadmat work for smaller .mat files?  In other words, is the issue with the file size, or the loadmat itself?

Comment: Its not with loadmat as it works in python shell. there must be some issue with jupyter